# fontawesome with vue do not work

Tags: vue.js, font-awesome-5

Is there a way to install fontawesome in Vue? I tried few tutorials but they are all useless and do not work or icons are empty or plugin does not render at all!!!! I don't want to import the font by script, I want to install it in my application. I tried this tutorial (https://github.com/FortAwesome/vue-fontawesome) but whatever I did the icons do not render, maybe someone can point me to the solution?

Here is my code but the icons even do not render:

```
import FontAwesomeIcon from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome';


export default {
  name: 'App',
  components:{FontAwesomeIcon}
}

<template>
  <div id="app"><font-awesome-icon icon="spinner" /></div>
</template>
```

also, I get an error in the console:

> Check not find one or more icon(s) {prefix: "fas", iconName:
>   "spinner"} {}

Comment: Have you installed all three required packages? https://github.com/FortAwesome/vue-fontawesome#installation

Comment: Yes,  all 3 packages are installed in the fortawesome folder...

Comment: any error was threw out in your browser console?

Comment: yes i get this error "Check not find one or more icon(s) {prefix: "fas", iconName: "spinner"} {}". I just updated the question, thanks for reminding me.

Comment: Found this bug ~ https://github.com/FortAwesome/vue-fontawesome/issues/22. I think it's really just down to bad documentation

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you might be missing some dependencies. Please try

```js
<script>
import fontawesome from "@fortawesome/fontawesome";
import brands from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-brands";
// import 1 icon if you just need this one. Otherwise you can import the whole module
import faSpinner from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid/faSpinner"; 
import FontAwesomeIcon from "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome";

fontawesome.library.add(brands, faSpinner);
// or .add(brands, solid) if you need the whole solid style icons library/module

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    FontAwesomeIcon
  }
};
</script>
```

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/ov6o0xk23y

Comment: When i copy your code is working, thanks!!!! But do i have to import each icon to work? I was thinking that i can import one component and use this component for all icons same as i was doing with the script, is it possible?

Comment: If you plan to use a lot more than 1 icon under Solid style, you can just import the whole module. For example: import solid from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid". I updated my answer :)

Comment: Why I can not load file-invoice-dollar icon? T_T 

https://fontawesome.com/icons/file-invoice-dollar?style=solid

Answer (score 5):

Also, in the case that you are using multiple icons, it can be easier to import and load the whole set of icons e.g.

```
...        
import { fas } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
    
library.add(fas);
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Remember to load each icon that you are using. My icons weren't rendering because I forgot to **add them to the library**.

---

Template:

```html
<icon icon="lock" />
```

JS:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import {
  // import icons here
  faLock,
} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome';

import App from './App.vue';

// add icons to library here
library.add(faLock);

Vue.component('icon', FontAwesomeIcon);

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with:

**package.json**

```json
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.36",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
    "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^2.0.2",
```

Relying on a previous project where it worked, I upgraded `@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome` to `^3.0.0-4`, which fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the following warning and not getting the icons displayed:

```
"export 'default' (imported as 'FontAwesomeIcon') was not found in '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'
```

Solution for me was to import an specific portion instead of going to default

changed from:

```
import FontAwesomeIcon from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'
```

to

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'
```