# How to use fortawesome with vue

Tags: vue.js, font-awesome

I did necessary installs based on instructions at https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome

```
$ npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
$ npm i --save @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
$ npm i --save @fortawesome/vue-fontawesome
```

in `src/main.js` added this:

```
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { faUserSecret } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'

library.add(faUserSecret)

Vue.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon)

Vue.config.productionTip = false
```

in `MyComponent.vue`

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <font-awesome-icon icon="user-secret" />
  </div>
</template>
```

It worked.

But none of these work.

```
<font-awesome-icon icon="shopping-cart" />
<font-awesome-icon :icon="['fas', 'shopping-cart']" />
```

I get error

```
Could not find one or more icon(s) {prefix: "fas", iconName: "shopping-cart"} {}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fontawesome with vue do not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50053163/fontawesome-with-vue-do-not-work)

Comment: yes, it answers my question.

Answer (score 2):

I had to add load each icon

```
import {
  faUserSecret,
  faShoppingCart
} from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

library.add(faUserSecret, faShoppingCart);
```

Comment: why dont you do like this `import Icons from "@fontawesome/free-solid-svg-icons"; library.add(Icons)`

Comment: Each icon is exported in @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons(@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons/index.d.ts). There is no default or Icons exported. How would that work?

Comment: `import { fas } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icon'` then add to library